# Promise is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I try to rewrite below code using Promise but got error of readFile is not a function error.

```
fs.readFile(data.file.path, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.

      const s3data = {
        Key: file_name,
        Body: data,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
      }

      s3Bucket.putObject(s3data, function(err, resp){
          if(!err) res.json({resp});
      });
    })
```

My attempt

```
const readFile = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(data.file.path, (err, data) => {
          resolve(data)
        })
      })
    }

    readFile.then(data => {
      const s3data = {
        Key: file_name,
        Body: data,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
      }

      s3Bucket.putObject(s3data, function(err, resp){
          if(!err) res.json({resp});
      });
    })
```

What's wrong? Another question I want to ask is should I use bluebird? I'm using node version 6.9, what's bluebird for? I thought es6 has its own Promise already?

Comment: You're sure it isn't `readfile.then` is not a function, as it should be `readfile().then...`

Comment: Is it `Promise` or `readFile` that's not a function? Your title and description don't seem to match. Also, you're calling `readFile.then` as if it were an object with a `then` method. It's `readFile(...args).then(...)`

Comment: `I thought es6 has its own Promise already` - yes, but a) nodejs hasn't always had "native" Promises and b) Bluebird has some extra useful functions and c) Bluebird *used to be* more performant than even "native" Promises